# Issue saving combobox data, Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

I have problem with saving my combobox data. When saving fist time I don't have problem, but when I do it again with the same combobox value I receive the following error:

> **DbUpdateException was unhandled** An error occurred while updating the entries.

```
private void FillCombo1()
{
    context = new PhonebookEntities();

    comboBox1.DataSource = context.Cities.ToList();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "City";
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
private void FillCombo3()
{
    context = new PhonebookEntities();
    comboBox3.DataSource = context.Firmas.ToList();
    comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Firma";
    //comboBox3.Invalidate();
    comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
}


private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    context = new PhonebookEntities();
    int new_id;
    if (context.Books.Count() < 1)
    {
        new_id = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int curr_id = context.Books.Max(b => b.id);
        new_id = curr_id + 1;
    }
    Book newbook = new Book();
    newbook.id_firma = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedIndex.ToString());

    newbook.id      = new_id;
    newbook.name    = name1.Text;
    newbook.phone   = phone1.Text;
    newbook.phone2  = phone2.Text;
    newbook.note    = note.Text;
    context.Books.Add(newbook);
    context.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Записът е успешен");
    LoadBook();
}
```

[This is my database schema:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KBLv.jpg)

Comment: you could try to catch the exception and look into the inner exception, that should contain more information

Comment: Inner exception says that: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Book_City\". The conflict occurred in database \"Phonebook\", table \"dbo.City\", column 'id_city'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated"
and i can't find something wrong

Comment: this error seems to be quite clear, you have a foreign key constraint that prevents you the second save - the question is, why do you have this constraint? From what I see, you never set anything City-related

Comment: i find what happend when i select first item in combo it returns 0 like nothing is selected but now i dont how to fix it

Comment: the index is 0-based, so 0 naturally is the value for the first element

Comment: what are you even doing with the firma? you are taking the index (which is an int), turn it to a string, and then convert it back to int?